Использование переводчика — считается ли это за использование ИИ?
Подскажите, пожалуйста, если, например, я знаю ответ на вопрос, заданный на Stack Overflow (английская версия), могу ли я использовать переводчик, или это будет считаться за использование искусственного интеллекта (перевод с русского на английский)?
Ведь с определённой точки зрения, перевод текста, как правило, основан на технологиях машинного обучения для наилучшего перевода.
Но по факту я просто перевожу свой текст на другой язык, поэтому, мне кажется, что можно, верно?
Насколько я понимаю, запрет именно на генерацию текста ответа на вопрос с помощью chat-gpt etc, (единственное, где можно — "О себе" в профиле), я прав?

Не забывайте указывать ссылку на источник перевода :-)

Речь о том, чтобы скопировать результат работы программы переводчика как есть, или вы его вручную дорабатываете? И вообще, если вопрос про английский Stackoverflow, почему он здесь?

из личного опыта (сразу вспомнила, не удержалась, чтоб поделиться)... https://i.sstatic.net/9QSN8fNK.png (я вообще от слова совсем терминологию не знала, и вначале пути было не легко, на лету учила русские термины, переводчик часто подводил) То есть я русскоязычный человек, но программирование изучала не на русском. И меня буквально тут учили терминам, так что переводчик порой может зло подшутить. Я как стала потом делать =>(переводить, и искать по гугл значение, синонимы, формулировки, статьи, чтоб понять, что использую нужное слово) а так то переводчик использовать ДОЗВОЛЕНО

Лично я периодически перевожу вопросы/ответы с enSO, но переводчиком пользуюсь изредка и только для образования "подстрочника", который потом жестко перерабатываю. Пользоваться только переводчиком, не редактируя получившийся результат, — по-моему, не совсем корректно, поскольку он также может выдать полную чушь. Проверено.

Переводчиком пользоваться можно. Главное, чтобы ответ был хорошим, качественным, полезным и понятным.
Я и сам несколько ответов брал "из-за рубежа"))) Доводил ответы до ума, публиковал и приносил пользу.

Note: относительно ИИ у меня такое же отношение: если ответ от ИИ проверить на корректность, подправить в удобочитаемый КАЧЕСТВЕННЫЙ ответ, то проблем с ним не вижу совсем. А то причипились к бедолаге...

Проблема в том, что там качество не ночевало. Мне уже и идея "перевести через переводчик, затем вручную подредактировать" кажется сомнительной, как раз из-за того, что там сплошь победивший псевдо-ИИ. Они могут тупо несуществующие в целевом языке слова придумывать, либо транслитить неизвестные слова. Затраты на вычитку их шедевров выше, чем если каждое слово в бумажном словаре смотреть, как в школе.

@MSDN.WhiteKnight вы ошибаетесь. Иногда качество у ИИ очень даже замечательное. А если качество ужасное, возникает вопрос: зачем такое сознательно публиковать не доведя до нужной кондиции? По поводу "со словарём сидеть каждое слово смотреть": если у человека-переводчика такие ужасные познания в языке, то стОит отказаться от каких-либо переводов...А вообще, без всяких ИИ и переводчиков ответ может быть ужасного качества. Вывод простой: ключевая фигура при ответе - человек, который должен быть ответственнен за качество. Ужасный ответ не вина ИИ или других инструментов, а человека его публикующий

Генерация ответов с помощью нейросетей —  отправка запроса, с последующей генерацией текста, похожий на ответ.
Перевод с использованием ИИ — просто перевод с одного языка на другой, с использованием машинного перевода для улучшения качества, и не более того.
Поэтому, вероятно, это не является нарушением, ведь сам текст — авторский, не является созданным нейросетью, (а лишь преобразован, т.е. переведён).

Главное, что бы такое преобразование не было похоже на текст от ИИ. За переводчиками лучше тоже проверять

@SwaD да на самом деле если сгенерить через ИИ и проверить за ним, чтобы был нормальный человеческий ответ - то вполне ответ пойдёт и даже плюсы будут. Просто все прицепились именно "Сгенерированное ИИ будет набор каши", а то, что можно всё подредачить в удобоваримый правильный ответ - все как-то не рассматривают
